# If you store a document locally on one device and also has that app use iCloud, will it be available on other devices?

Tags: ios, icloud, data-synchronization, ipados

Take an application, say Pages. You have the document saved locally on one of your Apple devices. You also have Pages turned on in Settings > [name] > iCloud > Apps using iCloud > Pages. Will the same docs be available on other apple devices logged in with the same ID?

Answer (score 1):

The document would not be available on other devices unless you save it in iCloud (or on Desktop or Documents folder and you have Desktop & Documents folder syncing for iCloud enabled).

Comment: That's precisely what I said, right? (Also, I'm not saving the doc to iCloud Drive, I'm saving it locally on my iPad).